# Is this enough to show this is the delta distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $f$ be a probability distribution with $$\int xf(x) = 0, \quad \int x^2f(x) = 0$$
Clearly, Dirac's delta distribution is a candidate for $f(x)$. Is the previous constrain enough to prove that it is the *only* possibility?

Comment: @Dr.MV Not with a nonnegative function. (Note that the OP seems actually blocked by the misconception that every probability distribution has a density.)

Comment: @Did in the distribution sense, isn't it the case?

Comment: What is $f(x)$ "in the distribution sense"? If you want to use Schwartz's distributions formalism, please do so, but for real. At the moment, the meaning of the two formulas in your post with an integral sign, is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use a measure theoretic approach (as you are clearly not interested in densities): Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and assume that
$$\int x^2 d\mu(x)=0$$
This implies that the integrand $x^2=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. But because $x^2\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ we must have $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})=0$. Thus, all mass has to be concentrated at $0$ and you obtain the dirac measure.

Or, more compactly: your second assumption is enough to conclude the dirac distribution.